# How to subtract Instants and compare with a Duration in jOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I'm trying to write this query with jOOQ for Postgres:

```sql
SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE t.instant1 - t.instant2 > interval '1 days';
```

So I wrote this:

```java
Duration oneDay = Duration.ofDays(1);
using(configuration)
    .selectFrom(MY_TABLE)
    .where(MY_TABLE.INSTANT1.minus(MY_TABLE.INSTANT2).gt(oneDay))
```

But it doesn't compile because of:

> Cannot resolve method 'lt(java.time.Duration)'

I tried wrapping `oneDay` in a `val()` and then the error changed to:

> Cannot resolve method 'lt(org.jooq.Param)'

I think the issue is the method `minus` returns a `Field<Instant>` instead of a `Field<Duration>`, but in Postgres, when subtracting 2 `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` the result is an `interval`.

Along these lines, jOOQ even allowed me to write this query that would fail at runtime as the types won't line up:

```
using(configuration)
    .selectFrom(MY_TABLE)
    .where(MY_TABLE.INSTANT1.minus(MY_TABLE.INSTANT2).gt(Instant.now()))
```

Is there any other jOOQ method I can use? besides doing something like:

`"{0} - {1} > interval '1 day'"`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jOOQ 3.12 still has a few limitations with respect to interval and interval arithmetic support. The best approach I can think of here is to change your expression:

```sql
t.instant1 - t.instant2 > interval '1 days'
```

To the equivalent

```sql
t.instant1 > t.instant2 + interval '1 days'
```

Which is easy to represent in jOOQ:

```java
T.INSTANT1.gt(T.INSTANT2.plus(1))
```

Comment: How is `.plus(1)` translated to `+ 1 days` ?

Comment: Cool! I see in the documentation that day is the default unit. It would be nice if this was specified explicitly. I wonder how to subtract hours, or minutes.

Comment: @Olayinka: An additional date time arithmetic manual page is on the roadmap. I'll be happy to answer your question if you ask a new one.